# ¿Se puede llamar stored procedure en un cursor loop?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

¿Existe la manera de realizar un llamado a un stored procedure dentro de un cursor loop de la siguiente manera?

```
            FOR LOOP_T1 IN (
                            SELECT
                                F1,
                                F2,
                                F3
                            FROM
                                T1
                            WHERE
                                F1 > 12
                            ) LOOP

                            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LOOP_T1.F1);
                            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LOOP_T1.F2);
                            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LOOP_T1.F3);

                            PROCESA_DATOS(LOOP_T1.F1, LOOP_T1.F2, LOOP_T1.F3);


            END LOOP LOOP_T1;
```